# 3 different times on my Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, cpanel

I have a wordpress website hosted at Hostgator (Brazil).
The server shows the current correct time (in daylight saving time). In this example, the correct time is as below, ie 13h **(America / São Paulo)**. Logging in via `putty.exe`:

```
user@site.com.br [~] # date
```

> Sun Nov 11 13:55:01 -02 2018 << - **correct time** / daylight saving time
>   America / São Paulo

However, inside a PHP script, I get the **time in 2 hours**:

```
echo date ("e / d-m-Y G: i: s");
```

> UTC / 11-11-2018 15:55:01

At the same time, within Wordpress (Admin -> Settings -> General), the "Time Zone" field is set to `UTC-3` where it shows:

> Universal time (UTC) is `11/11/2018 15:55:01`. Local time is 11/11/2018 12:55:01.

In short, the server shows `13h` (correct in current time in São Paulo DST), but PHP shows`15h` and Wordpress shows `12h`.

How to regularize this, that is, that the 3 cases have the same time?

Comment: Did you checked your php timezone? http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
The other times can be caused due different Server, PHP and Apache Settings, not sure though how your setup is, but to get execution time correct -> set the default timezone.

Comment: I got a very lucid answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/318928/143330